# What would happen to a bounty awarded on a migrated, merged question?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties, migration, merged-questions

Suppose **Question A** had a bounty placed on it, and then an exact duplicate **Question B** with answers on it (that were written after the bounty was set) was migrated from a different site, and merged with it.

Whether through the automatic selection or through manual awarding, the bounty is awarded to an answer whose author does not have an account here, because they answered **Question B**.

Can this happen, and if so, what happens to the reputation? Does it get lost? Awarded on association?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate question. This question what happens if a bounty is awarded to an "authorless" answer (say via migration) and the author later associates an account. The proposed duplicate asks what happens to reputation awarded from a bounty if the question is later migrated.

Comment: I've edited my question to make it clearer; I don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: The answer on the dupe still holds: "The user who was awarded the bounty loses the full amount immediately upon migration, and the user who offered it will regain that amount once the migration stub gets deleted" /cc @Arthur.

Comment: @ShadowWizard But for this question the migration happens _before_ the bounty is set, not _after_ it is awarded.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Really? That seems like a completely different scenario with different circumstances, if that's the answer then fair enough. But it really doesn't seem like a duplicate. And if it is, it arrives at the answer from a completely different starting point. It'd be like saying "the question is put on hold" is the answer and "what happens when a gold tag holder votes votes a question a duplicate" & "what happens when five users vote a question as off-topic" are the questions. :/

Comment: @ArthurFischer oh, so it is more about merging than about migration. Reopened.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's a very weird edge case. For a slightly less contrived example: User987 asks a question on Site A and receives an _exemplary_ answer by user123 who does not have an account on Site B. But the question is not on-topic on Site A, and is migrated to Site B. On Site B user987 decides to give a bounty to this _exemplary_ answer, and it is awarded before user123 creates their Site B account. Does user123 receive the bounty reputation when they later create their associated Site B account? (I can imagine this happening when Site A is [mathoverflow.se] and Site B is [math.se].)

Comment: @ArthurFischer fwiw it very nearly happened, except the proposed migration source was too old.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bounty in this scenario functions like any other reputation gained from the post. It sits in limbo with any other reputation gained from the post. Once the author gets associated to the post, the bounty also gets assigned to the user and the automatic reputation recalc will include that bounty amount along with the rest of the votes. For these purposes, a bounty award is still recorded as a "vote" in the database, just a different type of vote.